# Tipos de VPN's mais seguras

Tags: segurança, vpn

Estou com um projeto pronto em minha empresa onde uso pfsense na borda da rede, o equipamento faz o papel de Proxy, Firewall, gateway e VPN com certificado SSL, porem uma terceirizada ao vir implantar um acesso a nuvem ponto a ponto precisa utilizar dessa rede já configurada, e pede para que possamos utilizar VPN pptp ou L2tp, gostaria de saber qual dessas é a mais segura para o meu projeto, pensando nos dados da empresa que vão ser trafegados para o ambiente de terceiros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soluções que usam apena o L2TP não são indicadas para trafegar dados por redes publicas, pois o trafego não é criptografado, a solução se torna mais segura e completa quando é integrada com o IPSec. Ou seja, a solução que você deve buscar entre as duas que você listou é a L2TP/IPSec, que é o tunelamento de dados na layer 2 mais a criptografia de layer 3.

Segue tabela com uma breve comparação entre os tipos mais comuns de VPN:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]